# I can not load data on AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an old script which is loading IP from xml file.
Everything was working fine half year ago on that script. Now i wanted to use that again and it is not working. I don't know what happened. Is there something changed on browser or...  ?
Here is the Javascript

```
                    $.ajax({
                        var host;
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "config/config3.xml",
                        async : false,
                        dataType: "xml",
                        success: function(xml) {

                            $(xml).find('config').each(function () {
                                host = $(this).find('ip').text();
                                alert(host);
                            });

                        },
                        error: function(xml) {
                            alert("No XML file");
                        }
                    });
```

And XML called config3.xml

```
<config><ip>192.168.0.102</ip></config>
```

It is not working at all. Nothing happened. No errors. Just nothing. Please help

Comment: First of all, your have invalid syntax.  `var host;` is in the improper location.  Place it outside of your object you pass into the `ajax` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might lie in the fact that you have an improperly formed object.

Remove `var host;`

HTML

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "config/config3.xml",
        async : false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            console.log('xml success', xml);
            var host;
            $(xml).find('config').each(function () {
                host = $(this).find('ip').text();
                alert(host);
            });

        },
        error: function(xml) {
            alert("No XML file");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you see in your console? Is there any warnings or errors?

Comment: Also, add the console.log I just put in the success callback

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined. Just this

Comment: That means jQuery isn't loaded in your html page.

Comment: Yes. The problem was with Jquery. It was there but something had to be broken. I downloaded new one and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "config/config3.xml",
     async : false,
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function(xml) {
         var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml)
         xmlDoc.find('config').each(function () {
             host = $(this).find('ip').text();
             alert(host);
         });

     },
     error: function(xml) {
         alert("No XML file");
     }
 });
```